# Wildcards gobbling

Tags: wildcards

Wildcards

An asterisk (*) – matches one or more occurrences of any character, including no character.

Can anyone explain what is this “ including no character”  means?

Comment: s/gobbling/globbing/ ?

Answer (score 5):

[Bash's manual phrases it a bit differently](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) (just to pick some source):

> `*` Matches any string, including the null string

The "null string" is the zero-length string, so the meaning is that `*` matches any number of any characters, even none at all. Or, zero or more of any character.

`foo*bar` matches e.g.

- `foo1bar` (where the `*` matches one character)
- `foo22bar` (two chars)
- but also just `foobar`, where the `*` matches the zero-length string between `foo` and `bar`.

etc.

(Also, `*.txt`  would also match the filename `.txt`, but filenames starting with dots are a special case and don't get matched unless the dot is explicitly given in the pattern, or if something like Bash's `dotglob` is set.)

If you want to require at least one character, you can use `?*` since `?` requires and matches exactly one character.

Comment: I’m just beginning to study Linux ,Ihow can it mache 0 matches?cant make sense of it.

Comment: @user599592, "how" in what sense? I don't understand what you mean. It's just defined and implemented so that it doesn't require there to be any characters there.

Comment: @user599592 As ilkkachu showed, the pattern `foo*bar` matches the string `foobar`, which means that the `*` inside that pattern is allowed to match nothing.